# Regular expression to exclude a string/character in nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex

Currently I have a variable that has turnallplugsoffR1, turnallplugsonR1.
I wanted to exclude R1 from the string and get only turnallplugsoff in my variable in nodejs.
Could you please help me in achieving the same?
dataval="turnallplugsoffR1"

```
var room_value=dataval.match(/R[0-9]+/i); //matched R1/R2 any other string
    console.log(excl); // i want only turnallplugsoff. I dont want R1/R2 
    console.log(room_value[0]);
```

Comment: What about `var room_value=dataval.replace(/R\d+$/, '')`?

Comment: No Wiktor. It is just giving the first character in the string. only 't'

Comment: No, it yields [what you need](https://jsfiddle.net/ckjm12v8/). Or do you want to split the `dataval` into two parts?

Comment: oops my bad. The answer you told is correct. I was referring to 0th index . Its perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove `R` followed with any 1+ digits at the end of the string:

```
var room_value=dataval.replace(/R\d+$/, '')
```

**Details**

- `R` - a `R` letter
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var dataval="turnallplugsoffR1";
var room_value=dataval.replace(/R\d+$/, '');
console.log(room_value);
```

You may also get both the values with one matching operation using

```
dataval.match(/^(.*)(R\d+)$/)
```

Here, `^` matches the start of the string, `(.*)` captures into Group 1 any 0+
 chars other than line break chars up to the last `R` followed with digits at the end of the string `(R\d+)$` capturing the `R`+digits into Group 2.

See the JS demo:

```js
var dataval="turnallplugsoffR1";
var res = dataval.match(/^(.*)(R\d+)$/);
if (res) {
  console.log(res[1]); // turnallplugsoff
  console.log(res[2]); // R1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string with R1 and get the value you want.

```
dataval="turnallplugsoffR1"
var room_value= dataval.split('R1');
alert(data[0]);
```